# google analytics on the modern Sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, google-analytics

Could you tell me please, how to insert Google Analytics on the modern Sharepoint online site? Where is the best place to store the script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Clarity](https://clarity.microsoft.com/google-analytics) to integrate Google Analytics in your SharePoint Modern Site.

Below are the guideline to do so:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/ga-integration/ga-integration